# MIning Reward Pool vs Solo-mining?

Tags: mining-pools, solo-mining

I am about to invest in mining big time and questions regarding mining solo. I'm building a system consisting of 10 units with 168Mh/s of processing power. Is my effort on the pool calculated all togheter?
Where can I find a pool that pays ether for the amount of what you have done. 
Like if you mine for 1ETH you get 1ETH and pay a fee on that.

Should i mine Pool or Solo? Where can I mine Solo? if my processing power is calculated all togheter is 1680Mh/s good for solo?

I am starting to get this togheter but I need some help with pool selection.

Comment: I hear that 1.5 GHs is good for solo mining. I am thinking of doing the same thing and wondering what your experience has been like so far?

Comment: Did you end up selecting a pool to mine? or have gone the Solo route? If a pool, which pool, are you happy?

Answer (score 1):

The pool cannot pay you with 1 eth less fee if you get 1 ether. The principle is to share any gain between all participants, proportionally to their contribution in terms of valid share founds. So your contribute could be to find the winning solution for one block and to contribute for other fourtynine blocks or whatever without winning none of them and to receive 1/50 of the reward for your winning solution and 1/50 of some other winning solution the pool submit. Usually the less computing power you have respect to the entire network computing power, the less is it convenient to go in solo mining. A rough evaluation can be made dividing the overall network power by your computing power. This is the theoretical MAXIMUM probability to win in solo mode.

Answer (score 0):

pool mining is generally easier and ensures you get a regular return on a 1.5 ghs you can get a daily pay out 
with solo mining it all depends on luck if you find a block or not 
if you're just starting out "big time" then it may be a good idea to start pool mining and then once you have built confidence on how things work switch to solo mining hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

why mining pool reward blocks my money and if I don't pay before 7 days, what will happen.

thanks in advance

Sincerely

DJABERT HERAOUI

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/93118)